# Calculating a base price with surcharge conditions

Tags: functional-programming, comparative-review, scala

The following code has a lot of conditionals. I am trying to write
it in a functional programming way.

```
val basePrice = {
  var b = 0.0

  if (runtime > 120)
    b += 1.5
  if ((day == Sat) || (day == Sun))
    b += 1.5
  if (!isParquet)
    b += 2
  if (is3D)
    b += 3
  b
}
```

I think the following code would be a good approach, but maybe I am
complicating this too much.

```
val basePrice = {
  List((runtime > 120, 1.5), 
       (day == Sat || day == Sun, 1.5),
       (!isParquet, 2.0),
       (is3D, 3.0)).foldLeft(0.0)((acum, cond) =>
     if (cond._1) acum + cond._2 else acum)
}
```

How would you write the first snippet of code using functional
programming?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each condition is a function. It might be that you could write it more concisely, but I think the code is clearer if you do this:

```
def priceFunction(cond: => Boolean)(mod: Double => Double) = (_: Double) match {
    case x if cond => mod(x)
    case y => y
}

val modRuntime = priceFunction(runtime > 120)(_ + 1.5)
val modWeekend = priceFunction(day == Sat || day == Sun)(_ + 1.5)
val modParquet = priceFunction(!isParquet)(_ + 2.0)
val mod3d = priceFunction(is3D)(_ + 3.0)
val modifiers = List(
    modRuntime,
    modWeekend,
    modParquet,
    mod3d
)
val modifierFunction = modifiers reduceLeft (_ andThen _)                   

val basePrice = modifierFunction(0.0)
```

The name of the identifiers here suck, and I could have written `val modifiers = modRuntime andThen modWeekend andThen modParquet andThen mod3d` without trouble. I choose putting them in a `List` because it shows how well it can scale.

One could also make `PartialFunction` and chain them with `orElse`, for the cases where you want only the first condition.

You see this kind of thing used in web frameworks, such as BlueEyes, Lift or Unfiltered, for example.

Comment: You've littered the code with one-shot vals, things which are unlikely to be directly re-used. Why not create a list of anonymous functions, at least? "modifiers = List( priceFunction(runtime > 120)(_ + 1.5), priceFunction(day == Sat || day == Sun)(_ + 1.5). etc, etc )".  Frankly, I think simao's second example is as good as yours.

Comment: @itsbruce For two reasons. First, the identifier name helps one understand what the function is doing. Second, functions are syntactically noisy, so it's difficult to see where one ends and another starts in a list, whereas the `val` declarations make that obvious. The main question is: why _not_ declare them as `val`? It's not as if there would be any difference in memory usage or performance.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little bit more readable:

```
val basePrice = List((runtime > 120, 1.5), 
       (day == Sat || day == Sun, 1.5),
       (!isParquet, 2.0),
       (is3D, 3.0)).collect{case (true, b) => b}.sum
```

Comment: Scala noob here. Would this cause the list to be traversed twice? One for collect and another for sum? Or scala is aware of that and chains it properly?

Comment: I think it would be traversed twice, but I really hope you don't want to chain hundreds of these...

Comment: Note that you can use `.view` on lists to make them lazy (and, hence, traversed once).

Answer (score 0):

I like Daniel C. Sobral's answer. Anyway, in addition to the `List(...).sum` alternatives, there's:

```
val basePrice = {
  0.0 +
    (runtime > 120 ? 1.5 | 0) +
    ((day == Sat) || (day == Sun) ? 1.5 | 0) +
    (!isParquet ? 2 | 0) +
    (is3D ? 3 | 0)
}
```

Where `?|` is the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706056/694469).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write it like this:

```
val basePrice = 0.0 +
  (if (runtime > 120) 1.5 else 0) +
  (if (day == Sat || day == Sun) 1.5 else 0) +
  (if (!isParquet) 2 else 0) +
  (if (is3D) 3 else 0)
```

Comment: This is not more functional, just a slightly different way of writing the same code.